# ¿Cómo controlar una condición para verificar cuando existan o no usuarios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, condiciones

Estoy consumiendo un api, esta me retorna `null` si no existen usuarios en la base de datos.
El problema que tengo es con el `else`

```
else {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>No hay informacion para mostrar</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

El primer render se ejecuta porque la  página carga por primera vez, en este momento es su valor inicial es `null`.

Cuando esto sucede, se ejecuta el mensaje "No hay información para mostrar" y quiero evitar esto, ya que se puede percibir cuando se muestra el mensaje (dura alrededor de 1 segundo o menos),

Código:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getUsers } from "../../../services/user/UserDataService";

const EmployeeHomeView = function () {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function GetRequest() {
      const result = await getUsers();
      setUsers(result);
    }
    GetRequest();
  }, []);

  if (Array.isArray(users) && users.length > 0) {
    return (
      <>
      // Existen usuarios
      // Muestra una tabla de todos los usuarios
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>No hay informacion para mostrar</h1>
      </>
    );
  }
};
export default EmployeeHomeView;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes el ejemplo funcionando en: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-christian-c72kw?file=/src/EmployeeHomeView.js

Como bien dices, hay 3 estados y se está mostrando uno mientras aún no hay información, entonces mi recomendación sería, has render de los 3 estados:

- Si `users` es `null`
- Si `users` es Arreglo y tiene un elemento
- Cualquier otra cosa.

El código sería:

```js
  if (users == null) {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }
  
  if (Array.isArray(users) && users.length > 0) {
    return (
      <>
        {users.map(user => <p>{user.name}</p>)}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>No hay informacion para mostrar</h1>
      </>
    );
```

Comment: El enlace que publicaste está vacio, gracias ! ya entendi, modifique el tu if, me quedo asi: `users === null || users === undefined`

Comment: Disculpa, tienes razón, igual lo actualicé para que sea útil para alguien más en el futuro: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-christian-c72kw?file=/src/EmployeeHomeView.js